# Use query's hidden columns/fields in MS Access report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a query which joins a few tables. The query asks for a parameter when it is run. Then it displays a few columns/fields from its results, the other fields (like, the entered parameter and other fields that are common to all rows) are hidden. I'm trying to create my first Access report based on this query and I'd like to use some of these hidden fields as a record source for text-boxes/labels but I've been unable to do so. Those fields don't appear in the list of possible record sources.

I've tried the `Add Existing Fields` button and selecting the field I want from `Fields in related tables` but when the bound textbox shows up in the report with an error like `Invalid Control Property. No Such Field in the Field List` which I think means the fields are still invisible to the report. Would appreciate any help getting this done.

Comment: Why do you bother hiding fields in query? Users should not work with tables and queries. So apparently if they are hidden they are not available. The solution is to not hide. I never use dynamic parameterized query, especially not with a popup input as cannot validate user input.

Comment: @June7 This isn't for users, it's just something I'm working on to learn Access and ultimately SQL. So there's no way to use hidden or non-SELECTed fields in a report, even if the fields do exist in the related tables that yielded the query results?

Comment: Certainly not non-SELECTed. I've never tried for hidden so I defer to results of your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers is to edit the query and include the missing columns so that they are available to the report.

For non-selected query columns, the *use of the word "hidden" is misleading*. The way that SQL works--even beyond SQL in the overall concept of datasets--is that only **subsets** of data are requested in a query. If certain columns are not selected in a query, they are plainly and simply NOT available in the resultant dataset.

It may be possible to re-aquire the excluded columns with another query, but that still does not imply that missing columns were just "hidden".  In the case of a subsequent query to get different columns of data, the database engine must re-analyze the new query, re-read the data, then compile the data from the new set of columns to be returned in a completely new subset of data.  It is a complete round-trip process that is much more involved than just un-hiding the data.

Forms and reports are completely different types of objects that can mark fields as "hidden", but a query is not the same despite being displayed in a datasheet.  Objects like Access Forms and Recordset objects in (VBA) code are designed to *hold subsets of queried data*, so they are able to temporarily hide (or ignore) or un-hide certain fields without re-querying the database.  (Technically an Access Form has its own Recordset object for holding and managing queried data.)

Even though Access is "self contained" with both database and user-interface elements, it is still primarily a standard RDBMS (Relational Database Management System).  The principle idea in efficient data handling of an RDBMS is to get only what you need for the current operation.  Consider that SQL can be used to query data from a remote server. Even Access can get data from and update data on SQL Server, for example. If data fields were only "hidden" when not included in a query, that would imply that the entire database (or at least an entire table) would be passed back and forth, and that the only thing hindering getting at any column would be "making it visible" as though it is actually immediately available. That would be terribly inefficient both for memory and for remote communications.

Comment: Indeed. There is no such thing as *hidden columns* in a SELECT query, columns are either included in the SELECT list (explicitely or via `.*`) or they are not. @TisteAndii